# Compiling c code with my_global.h, main function is OK but nothing else

Tags: mysql, c, program-entry-point, void

I can't compile the code when i'm including my_global.h.

This is not supposed to be a main function, since data before is "collected" by code in another c file thar together with this one will be the program (using external variables, which is not in the code yet).

My problem is that I can not compile the code when the function is other than "main". I made a very simple example below, so if i replace "void test() {" with "void main() {" in below example compiling is OK. Keeping "test" but removing #include my_global.h is also OK. But in the final code of course I need my_global.h, so I can't remove it. So the combination of not main and my_global.h gives me this problem.

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "extvar.h"

void test() {
printf("Testing testing\n");
}
```

I'm compiling with `$ gcc -c testa.c -o testa.o 'mysql_config --cflags --libs'`.

Error message:

```
In file included from testa.c:1:0:
/usr/include/mysql/my_global.h:478:21: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘)’ token
 #define test(a)  ((a) ? 1 : 0)
                     ^
testa.c:7:6: note: in expansion of macro ‘test’
 void test() {
      ^
```

I'm very thankful for your help.

Comment: Apparently there is a macro named `test`. And a function named `test`. Guess what? You have confused the compiler. And yes, the error message is *extremely* clear.

Comment: Yes, rename your function to `my_test()` that would also be funny! Because all `MySQL` stuff have a `my` and now you will need one in order to include `my_`.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Could always go with `real_my_test` as is apparently tradition in the MySQL API.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined your function to have the same name as a macro defined in mysql/my_global.h.  As a result, the name of the function gets macro substitution done on it.

The macro expects an argument, but your function declaration, looks like a function-like macro call that has no arguments, so you get an error.

Define your function to have some name other than `test` and you should be fine.